# How can I bind a partial view to a model in a layout view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout view for a specific section (group of  views) in my MVC4 application, and this layout should contain a dynamic treeview with navigation options for views that use this layout view. E.g. My layout view says each dependent view will have a treeview at the left. Now the only way I can think of properly loading this treeview in the layout for each dependent view is have it as a mandatory section in each dependent view, and use a common base viewmodel for each dependent view that carries a viewmodel for the treeview. This seems very awkward. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I have understood your question properly, but I think the concept you are looking for is known as "Child Actions" - see [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) on MSDN.

This lets you do something conceptually similar to `RenderPartial` in your view, but rather than having to pass it a model, `RenderAction` lets you create an action to retrieve the model.

This frees you from your view needing the models for each partial view.

Comment: I knew there was something like that, but had no idea what it was. Thanks.